cannot load such file --json (LoadError) whenever trying to create a new rails app
I am trying to create a rails app using: rails new app_name
I am getting the error pasted below. I looked around but haven't been able to find a solution.
I am on linux if that matters. Going to install ruby on windows and try there for now.
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 81 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Writing lockfile to /home/isaac/git/frameworks/ruby/rails_blog/test_app/Gemfile.lock
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
       rails  importmap:install
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/isaac/git/frameworks/ruby/rails_blog/test_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
        from /home/isaac/git/frameworks/ruby/rails_blog/test_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require': cannot load such file -- json (LoadError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:17:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:49:in `init!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/json.rb:42:in `install!'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:34:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:68:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.18.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/isaac/git/frameworks/ruby/rails_blog/test_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
        from /home/isaac/git/frameworks/ruby/rails_blog/test_app/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'


I cannot determine why you are experiencing this. Have you tried gem install json? What I can say is "Going to install ruby on windows and try there for now.", is a step backwards and while maybe you can resolve this issue the number of other issues you will experience is far greater.

I would try to install the latest Ruby version (3.3.0) first. It seems you are using the 3.0.0 version, and it possibly can cause some dependency issues.

Just a hint on what I did. I'm using pacman as my package manager and in the end had to give up on using the provided ruby from it. What I did is I installed rbenv - ruby and gem now work properly through it - I had some privileges issue with the pacman ruby package. Also rails new can now find json package without issues. Hope this helps!
